# Containers with pipelines: should/can you keep your data separate from the container

Tags: docker, containers, pipeline

I am very new to containers and I was wondering if there is a "best practice" for the following situation:

Let's say I have developed a general pipeline using multiple software tools to analyze next generation sequencing data (I work in science). I decided to make a container for this pipeline so I can share it easily with colleagues. The container would have the required tools and their dependencies installed, as well as all the scripts to run the pipeline. There would be some wrapper/master script to run the whole pipeline, something like: bash run-pipeline.sh -i input data.txt

My question is: if you are using a container for this purpose, do you need to place your data INSIDE the container OR can you run the pipeline one your data which is place outside your container? In other words, do you have to place your input data inside the container to then run the pipeline on it?

I'm struggling to find a case example.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me the answer is obvious - the data belongs outside the image.

The reason is that if you build an image with the data inside, how are your colleagues going to use it with their data?

It does not make sense to talk about the data being inside or outside the container.  The data will be inside the container.  The only question is how did it get there?

My recommended process is something like:

1. Create an image with all your scripts, required tools, dependencies, etc; but not data.  For simplicity let us name this image `pipeline`.
2. Bind mount data in volumes to the container.  `docker container create --mount type=bind,source=/path/to/data/files/on/host,target=/srv/data,readonly=true pipeline`

Of course, replace /path/to/data/files/on/host with the appropriate path.  You can store your data in one place and your colleagues in another.  You make a substitution appropriate for you and they will have to make a substitution appropriate for them.

However inside the container, the data will be at /srv/data.  Your scripts can just assume that it will be there.

Comment: Ok thanks. I'm just not sure I understand how the container in the pipeline could "connect" to my files, if my files are not in the container. But you are saying that the first step, after launching the container, would be to place my files in it?

Comment: @m93 more or less yes.  I will update my answer with more details.

Comment: thanks @emory ! So if I understand well, by mounting the data, I don't have to "move" that data at all, I am merely sharing a folder between my computer OS and the container, right? 

One last thing: this "docker container create" command, would the mount persist after I stop the container running with "Docker stop" (if for some reason I had to stop it?) Or would I have to remount the folder each time I start up the container again?

Comment: Yes.  I think this is a good thing.  I want to apply your awesome pipeline on my data. 
 Why would I want to apply your pipeline to your data - that is your job.  The mount would persist between stop and restarting the container.  If you `docker container rm` your container then the mount would cease to exist - removing the container removes the mount.

Comment: Thanks @emory! So sorry but one last question: if this Docker image was launched on a server that me and all my colleagues have access to, presumably we could just launch it once, and leave it permanently - then whenever me or my colleagues need to run the pipeline, we connect to the server (that we all have access to as the same user) and we run the pipeline on the data we want. Would that be a good way of sharing the pipeline? Although presumably, as long as my docker image is unchanged, each person could have a copy of the Docker image on their computer, i guess that's the point actually..?

Comment: @m93 that is a much different use case than I was anticipating.  Not to say that you are doing anything wrong, but maybe my advice is not applicable.

Answer (score 2):

To handle the described scenario I would recommend files to exchange data between your processing steps. To bring the files into your container you could mount a local directory into your container. That also enables some kind of persistence for your containers. The way how to mount local file system into your container is displayed in the following example.

```
version: '3.2'
services:
    container1:
        image: "your.image1"
        volumes:
            - "./localpath:/container/internal"
    container2:
        image: "your.image2"
        volumes:
            - "./localpath:/container/internal"
    container3:
        image: "your.image3"
        volumes:
            - "./localpath:/container/internal"
```

The example uses a docker compose file to describe the dependencies between your containers. You can implement the same without docker-compose. Then you have to specify your container mounts in your docker run command.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/